# How to select desired elements without using for-loop?

Tags: arrays, performance, matlab, for-loop, hashtable

I'm writing MATLAB code. The array `universe` has increasing integers (positive, no larger than 1000) as entries (not necessarily consecutive). It could be `[3,10,20,24,25,100,120,...,1000]` The length of `universe` is bounded by 200.

`Candidates` is a `2-by-k` array containing randomly selected entries from `universe` such that the first row is sorted and for each column, the first row is smaller than the second row. It looks like

```
Candidates = [3, 3, 20;
              10,25,24]
```

for `k=3`. Usually `k` is smaller than 1000. I know how to generate `Candidates` without for-loop.

`Nodes` is a `3-by-(n^2-n)` array, where the first and the second rows have entries from `universe`, and sorted such that the first row is the primary key and the second row is the secondary key. There is no constrain on the third row. It looks like

```
Nodes = [3,  3,  3,  20, 20, 20, 24, 24, 24, 25, 25, 25; 
         20, 24, 25, 3,  24, 25, 3,  20, 25, 3,  20, 24; 
         1,  2,  3,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  0,  3,  2,  1]
```

Basically the first row and the second row have the same multi-set, while the first row is sorted by grouping and the second row sorted by round-robin.

The question is, how can we select columns from `Nodes` such that `Nodes(1:2,i)` appears in one of `Candidates`'s column?

The naive way is

```
Result = [];
k = 3;
n = 4;
j_start = 1;
for i=1:(n^2-n)
  for j=j_start:k
    if isequal(Nodes(1:2,i),Candidates(:,j))
      Result = [Result,Nodes(:,i)];
      j_start = j+1;
      break;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Can we do it without `for`-loops? Any solutions like hashtable, contianer are welcome, as long as the efficiency can be improved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ismember` but you'll have to transpose because there is no `'columns'` flag:

```
Results = Nodes(:, ismember(Nodes(1:2,:)', Candidates', 'rows'))
```